# Dynamics CRM Option Set data into Azure Data Factory

Tags: dynamics-crm, azure-data-factory

I'm using Azure Data Factory to create a pipeline that retrieves data from the option set entity, however this fails with the following error:

Dynamics operation failed with error code: -2147219456, error message: The 'RetrieveMultiple' method does not support entities of type 'optionset'. MessageProcessorCache returned MessageProcessor.Empty. .
Activity ID: 00c29e02-b71f-45e5-bb10-e6bac862f305

I've seen some workarounds suggesting to use FetchXML, but I'm not sure how to incorporate this, and the solutions seem to suggest that I need to know some of the attributes in this entity.

What I'm currently trying is to use the Ingest wizard - I select my Dynamics CRM linked service (which works fine on other entities), select the option set entity and then configure my target as parquet files. Being new to ADF, I'm not sure how to embark on an alternative approach that uses FetchXML. And all I know about the data, is that in several other entities there are several fields containing IDs and I need to know the text value, or 'label' which I intend to achieve as a left join further in the process.

How can I proceed, in ADF, to get the contents of the option set table (all of it - as I'm trying to set up an automated process here).

Answer (score 0):

> error message: The 'RetrieveMultiple' method does not support entities of type 'optionset'.

As the error message indicates that method does not support means we can't do it any way.

> I'm not sure how to embark on an alternative approach that uses FetchXML.

For this workaround you need to use REST API given below.

```
https://crmdev.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/roletemplates?fetchXml=<fetch> <entity name="roletemplate" > <attribute name="name" /> <attribute name="roletemplateid" /> </entity> </fetch>
```

Replace the parameters with required values.

Use the Azure [REST API activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=data-factory) to load the data using API.